# @StreamListener doesn't work for secured Kafka streaming, TopologyException

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

My demo application has:

`application.yml`

```yaml
# some values to reduce duplicates in configuration
kafka-conf:
  server: kafka.host:9093
  topic-name: employee.test.incoming.json
  keystore: classpath:kafka_client_keystore.jks
  truststore: classpath:kafka_client_truststore.jks
  group: hr-test


spring:
  application:
    name: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
  kafka:
    security:
      protocol: SSL
    ssl:
      key-store-location: ${kafka-conf.keystore}
      key-store-password: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      key-store-type: JKS
      key-password: ${KEY_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-location: ${kafka-conf.truststore}
      trust-store-password: ${TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
      trust-store-type: JKS
    topicName: ${kafka-conf.topic-name}
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: ${kafka-conf.server}
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      group-id: ${kafka-conf.group}
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: ${kafka-conf.server}
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    bootstrap-servers: ${kafka-conf.server}
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        kafka-input-channel:
          contentType: application/json
          destination: ${kafka-conf.topic-name}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming # todo check me
      kafka:
        # todo check this
        bindings:
          kafka-input-channel:
            consumer:
              keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
              valueSerde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        binder:
          # confirmed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_example_security_configuration
          # + : https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#security_configclients
          configuration:
            [security.protocol]: SSL
            [ssl.truststore.location]: ${kafka-conf.truststore}
            [ssl.truststore.password]: ${TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.truststore.type]: JKS
            [ssl.keystore.location]: ${kafka-conf.keystore}
            [ssl.keystore.password]: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.key.password]: ${KEY_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.keystore.type]: JKS
            default:
              key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
              value.serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        streams:
          # confirmed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_consumer_properties
          default:
            consumer:
              application.id: ${kafka-conf.group}-default
          binder:
            brokers: ${kafka-conf.server}
```

`KafkaProducer`

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j(topic = "Producer Logger")
public class KafkaProducer {

    @Value("${kafka-conf.topic-name}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Message> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String key, Message message) {
        log.debug("sending message. where key: <{}>, message: <{}>", key, message);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    }
}
```

`KafkaConsumer`

```
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

@Service
@CommonsLog(topic = "Consumer Logger")
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private final List<Message> messages = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka-conf.topic-name}")
    public void receive(@Payload Message message,
//                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY) Integer key,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) int partition,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts) {
        messages.add(message);
        log.info(String.format("topic: %s", topic));
        log.info(String.format("Message saved: %s", message));
    }

}
```

### `KafkaStreamingConsumer`

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

@EnableBinding(KafkaSink.class)
@Service
@Slf4j(topic = "Streaming Consumer Logger")
public class KafkaStreamingConsumer {

    private final List<Message> messages = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    @StreamListener(KafkaSink.INPUT)
    public void consume(KStream<String, Message> message) {
        log.info("income detected.");
        message.peek((k, v) -> log.info("Key: {}, value: {}", k, v));
        log.info("Streamed message saved: {}", message);
    }

    public interface KafkaSink {

        String INPUT = "kafka-input-channel";

        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel kafkaInputChannel();
    }
}
```

### `KafkaStreamsConfig` - is an extraconfiguration

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde;

@Configuration
@Slf4j(topic = "Streaming Config Logger")
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {

    @Value("${kafka-conf.topic-name}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, Message> kStream(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        JsonSerde<Message> messageSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Message.class);

        KStream<String, Message> input = streamsBuilder.stream(topic,
                        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), messageSerde))
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Received message <{}>, key: <{}>", k, v));

        return input;
    }
}
```

`KafkaPocApplication`

```
the enter point
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafkaStreams;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaPocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaPocApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-poc</name>
    <description>PoC project that demonstrates how to work with kafka using java app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.1.5</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### Issue

`KafkaStreamingConsumer` doesn't work correctly, no logged information about problem, no input stream data. Checked documentation and yml configguration `@StreamListener(KafkaSink.INPUT)` should working in my case but it doesn't.
To reduce research cases i've created `KafkaStreamsConfig` and it works.
The main question is - how to make working secured kafka stream for case when topology configured in `yml` without extra java configurations (expect `@StreamListener`)?

### P.S.

The important points (i think important), i highlighted using header font.

### P.S.2

Experimented to start only secured streaming kafka consumer.

`yml reduced to

```
# some values to reduce duplicates in configuration
kafka-conf:
  server: kafka.host:9093
  topic-name: employee.test.incoming.json
  keystore: classpath:kafka_client_keystore.jks
  truststore: classpath:kafka_client_truststore.jks
  group: hr-test


spring:
  application:
    name: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        kafka-input-channel:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.topic-name}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-streaming # todo check me
      kafka:
        # todo check this
        bindings:
          kafka-input-channel:
            consumer:
              keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
              valueSerde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        binder:
          # confirmed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_example_security_configuration
          # + : https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#security_configclients
          configuration:
            [security.protocol]: SSL
            [ssl.truststore.location]: ${kafka-conf.truststore}
            [ssl.truststore.password]: ${TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.truststore.type]: JKS
            [ssl.keystore.location]: ${kafka-conf.keystore}
            [ssl.keystore.password]: ${KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.key.password]: ${KEY_PASSWORD}
            [ssl.keystore.type]: JKS
            [ssl.enabled.protocols]: TLSv1.2
            default:
              key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
              value.serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde
        streams:
          # confirmed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_consumer_properties
          default:
            consumer:
              application.id: ${kafka-conf.group}-default
          binder:
            brokers: ${kafka-conf.server}
```

`KafkaStreamingConsumer`

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamingConsumer.KafkaSink.class)
@Service
@Slf4j(topic = "Streaming Consumer Logger")
public class KafkaStreamingConsumer {

    private final List<Message> messages = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    @StreamListener(KafkaSink.INPUT)
    public void consume(KStream<String, Message> message) {
//    public void consume(KStream<String, String> message) {
        log.info("income detected.");
        message.peek((k, v) -> log.info("Key: {}, value: {}", k, v));
        log.info("Streamed message saved: {}", message);
    }

    public interface KafkaSink {

        String INPUT = "kafka-input-channel";

        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel kafkaInputChannel();
    }
}
```

and failed with `TopologyException` (similar configuration worked for me if kafka streams are not secured):

```
01:34:14.776 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
01:34:14.806 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:966)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.bayer.hrkafkapoc.KafkaPocApplication.main(KafkaPocApplication.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: 
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:354)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TopologyMetadata.getNumStreamThreads(TopologyMetadata.java:377)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:930)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:856)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:762)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:335)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It mainly depends on what is "doesn't work correctly". I would suggest changing the logger level to wither debug or trace and see if something shows up, also, is this `server: kafka.host:9093` dns actually defined in your environment?

Comment: Also another thing to look at is whether your producer is actually adding messages to the topic, I would test in separate, produce a message, check on kafka to see if the message is there and then test the consumer

Comment: read wither > whether :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos, i've just added P.S.2 to provide you more details after experimenting.

Comment: So then it is probably a configuration problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841137/topology-with-no-input-topics-will-create-no-stream-threads-and-no-global-thread

Comment: Another reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2230

Comment: Another thing to add is that your Spring Cloud version `2020.0.4` isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.1 for that you would need Spring Cloud version `2022.0.3` or up. Anything lower isn't officially supported on Spring Boot 3.x (and might even pull in older dependencies). You also don't need the `spring-boot-dependencies` in your `dependencyManagement` section, that is already taken care of by the parent you have (unless it was a fix to workaround incompatible versions due to yuour spring cloud version in use).

Comment: @M.Deinum, Invalid topology doesn't mean compatibility issue. And for note i verified your idea, issue still the same. P.S. `spring-boot-dependencies` in my `dependencyManagement` is just redundant.

Comment: Fact is it is incompatible leading to all sorts of issues. Invalid topology might not mean incompatibility it also doesn't mean that it is. Could be that the configuration mapping is added to newer versions and not in the older ones who knows. Fact is you should use compatible things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `@StreamListener` does not work. It's been deprecated for over 5 years and has now been completely removed. Please upgrade to functional style.